# Creating Python daemon - 'module' object has no attribute 'DaemonContext'

Tags: python, python-daemon

I'm trying to daemonize my app and am getting the error:

```
out:     with daemon.DaemonContext():
out: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DaemonContext'
```

It looks like other people are getting this error from the module not being installed.  As a newcomer to Python it's a bit confusing that there is a daemon and python-daemon package and also there's two ways of installing python packages (sudo apt-get install and sudo pip install).  However, it seems like I have the package installed.  I have Python 2.6 installed on Ubuntu 10.04.  Any ideas?

It looks like I have the module installed:

```
# pip freeze
LEPL==5.0.0
MySQL-python==1.2.2
distribute==0.6.10
lockfile==0.8
matplotlib==0.99.1.1
numpy==1.3.0
pyparsing==1.5.2
python-apt==0.7.94.2ubuntu6.4
python-daemon==1.5.2
python-dateutil==1.4.1
pytz==2010b
rpy2==2.0.8
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

More evidence the module is installed:

```
$ python
>>> import daemon
>>> dir(daemon)
['DaemonContext', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '_copyright', '_license', '_url', '_version', 'daemon', 'version']
```

Comment: I also had this problem, but it turned out I had done `pip2 install daemon` when I should have done `pip2 install python-daemon`, which solved it for me.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The program that produces the error is apparently using a *different* module named `daemon`. Did you perhaps call the program itself, or another module in the same directory, `daemon.py`?

If so, that will shadow the installed `daemon` module.

**The solution**

Rename `daemon.py` (and delete the `daemon.pyc` file that Python will have created) and try again.

If you don't see anything shadowing `daemon.py`, make your application print `daemon.__file__` and see where it is being imported from.

Comment: Thanks!  My script was named daemon.py and I didn't realize that would cause an issue.  Calling "print daemon.__file__" was very helpful as well.

Answer (score 21):

I run on this proglem too. If I call `print daemon.__file__` it prints `/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/daemon.pyc`, which is right file in wrong place, meaning that I have installed packege wrong way.

I used command "sudo pip install daemon", which installs only daemon.py file. We should use commnd
"sudo pip install python-daemon", which installs whole package. After that `print daemon.__file__`  prints `/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/daemon/__init__.pyc`, meaning that I have installed python-daemon -package, not just one python file daemon.py.

Confusing, but it was my own fault.

Remember to call "sudo pip uninstall daemon" before giving right installing command sudo pip uninstall python-daemon".

Answer (score 4):

```
pip uninstall daemon
pip install python-daemon
```